# How to use useNavigation to change button text and redirect in remix

Tags: javascript, typescript, remix.run

My OnboardingForm.tsx component is below.

```
import { useUser } from '@clerk/remix'
import { Form, useNavigation } from '@remix-run/react'
import { processFormData, setUserIsActiveTrue } from 'lib/user-actions'
import { ActionArgs, redirect } from '@remix-run/node'

export async function action({ request }: ActionArgs) {
  const form = await request.formData()

  try {
    const result = await processFormData(form)

    if (!result) {
      throw new Error('Form not submitted correctly.')
    }

    console.log('User created!')

    return redirect('/dashboard')
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error('Error in action:', error.message)
    throw new Error('Server error. Please try again later.')
  }
}

export default function OnboardingForm() {
  const navigation = useNavigation()

  return (
    <Form method="post">
      <div>
        <div>
          <input
            name="firstName"
            type="text"
            placeholder=" "
            required
          />
          <label>First name</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit" disabled={navigation.state === 'submitting'}>
            {navigation.state === 'submitting' ? 'Verifying...' : 'Verify'}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Form>
  )
}
```

When I click submit, button text changes to "Verifying" and the record goes to the database as intended. But return redirect('/dashboard') does not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try out these solutions;

1. Verify that the route `/dashboard` exists in your Remix routes configuration. Ensure that it's set up correctly and has the appropriate handler to render the dashboard page.
2. Check if the `redirect` function from `@remix-run/node` is being called properly. Make sure that it is imported correctly and that the `return redirect('/dashboard')` line is executed.

Comment: When I remove the navigation.state code from the button, it all works as intended. Reduction also works.